# MapNetworkDrive credential escaping special characters problem

Tags: powershell

I am actually mapping network drive with pgina at boot,
the only problem is i can't escape special characters like :"'

I use args[1] as input, but special characters like " transfoms into something else, i need to use them raw because i need to mount a user folder even with passwords with special characters.

```
$user = $args[0];
$password = $args[1];

$user = $user.Trim();
$user= $user.ToLower();
Write-Output "$user | $password" > c:\SCRIPTS\TMP\lastlog.txt;
$PSnet = $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network);

$smbserver = "172.18.49.101";
$userFolder="\\$smbserver\$user";

$PSnet.MapNetworkDrive("Z:", $userFolder, $false, "smbserver\$userid", $password;
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the password variable in curly brackets when you map the network drive::  ${password}

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I tried by using ${password} but it transforms the string: foobar'''' to foobar'' and bar"""" to bar

Comment: I think, it is the intrinsic mecanism of args[], i don't know others methods to take the input as a raw string.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.. How are you calling the script?

Comment: Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -file c:\SCRIPTS\example.ps1 "%o" "%p"

Comment: I use:  `Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -file c:\SCRIPTS\example.ps1 "%o" "%p"   ` and tried  `Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -file c:\SCRIPTS\example.ps1 %o %p  ` . I think it is executed from a BATCH command shell on Pgina.fork